# Org-mode: How to LaTeX export "$n$-" correctly?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have notes containing many of the following type of LaTeX fragments

```
$p$-adic ... $n$-th ...
```

But org-mode exports them as literal dollar sign instead of math. The problem seems to be the 
`-`
directly following the second dollar sign.

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the syntax of character `-` from symbol to punctuation in org-mode.
You can do that by:

```el
(defun my-org-change-minus-syntax-fun ()
  (modify-syntax-entry ?- "."))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my-org-change-minus-syntax-fun)
```

You can add these lines to your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Note that I have running that setup for ages now with no relevant negative effects.

Answer (score 3):

Org-mode translates `$n$` to `\(n\)` in latex. You can also directly write `\(n\)-doc` in the org file and it should export just fine.